# Can validation accuracy reach train accuracy?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I am training my neural network with shape 3585-500-95. And after some iterations I got something like this:

[image]

It seems the accuracy on validation set doesn't rise anymore. I have tried L2-regularization and dropout but made no difference. So I wonder whether this is the final status this nnet can get? And if it is normal to see the accuracy on validation set is lower than that on training set under regular circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  it is normal to see the accuracy on validation set to be lower than that on training set under regular circumstances.

If as you say have already used dropout, you are probably near the end of your training. If you want you can try different architectures of your model, more layers, higher dropout,...

More data would definitely help but if this is not possible and you would like to move one step further you could try pseudo-labeling. This will not help a lot but in most cases helps a bit.